# Removing Empty Cells From a Column in Excel

Tags: excel

Using Excel 2011 for Mac. I have a column of cells - some with values, and some empty. I want to have another column contain all of the values and no empty spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in column A, then, in some cell in a different column, enter the formula below and fill down until it returns blanks

This formula must be **array-entered**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$20,SMALL((ROW($A$1:$A$20)*(LEN($A$1:$A$20)>0)),COUNTBLANK($A$1:$A$20)+ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.

If you don't need the dynamic qualities of a formula, you could always use a filter.